# Displaying multiple symbols/patches for the one layer in an ArcMap legend

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.3, symbology, legend

I'm mapping incidents of an invasive species on a map, where the observations during surveying were recorded as points and also a line where there was a long continuous strip of the species along a bank. These two layers are displayed in the legend as this:

[image: How the two layers are arranged in the legend right now.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXJbk.png)

The two different symbols (point and line) ideally will sit beside each other in the legend or at least it will be communicated that both the point and the line represent the species, in one legend item.

I've achieved this by converting to graphics and ungrouping before (see knotweed example below).

[image: How I have displayed two patches for one legend item in the past.][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6kpc.png)

However, as I am using data driven pages to output several maps at once, I don't want to break my dynamic legend or for the converted graphics to appear across all the pages (this species is only relevant to this map), plus I expect the map to have to be updated in the future.

Can something like in the second examples above be achieved without converting to graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to display the two symbol on two column and set the left column as symbol only (not displaying the label). by playing with the spacing option you could get the look you're after minus the slash.

[image]

If you have more element in your legend you should add several legend item so these particular double symbol are in their own legend item, this way it's easier to get the right alignment for the whole legend and the whole legend isn't messed-up when they disappear.

Comment: This pretty much does what I wanted, thanks. Just to optimise this, is there a way to get around the 'indent' for the rest of the items that this method produces? Like because the rest of the legend is in the second column now, the item patches down the left do not sit flush. You get me? It's not a huge deal, tho it would be even better if that were possible.

Comment: that's why I suggest to create several legend item, by playing with the spacing option you could more or less get proper alignment

Answer (score 1):

You may try to place your legend in 3 columns i.e 1st Himalayan balsam point with "Show Label" property off, 2nd Point layer with a symbol "**/**" also with the "Show Label" property off and 3rd your Himalayan Balsam Line Layer. Your point layer with symbology "**/**" may not be in the extent of your area of interest because you don't need to display it on map just in legend.

For columns :
[image]

For Disabling Show Labels:

[image]

Hope it Helps

Comment: I wasn't aware of that show labels option there, i'd usually just change the layer style to just the description (which would be blank). Thanks for that.